# setTimeout not working with each loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to delay the each loop by using setTimeout.

```
  $(".video_nav .item_container > .item").each(function() {
var button = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(i) {
                 alert("test");
                button.trigger("click");

            },2000);
        });
```

The alert or the click events aren't firing.  Where did i go wrong?  I want each loop iteration to be 2 seconds.

Comment: Is the selector correct? if yes, then at-least `alert()` should work.

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @SLaks  i changed that and i should get an alert every 2 seconds but nothing?

Comment: I finally get an alert but what happens is after 2 seconds the alerts come one after another instead of 2 seconds inbetween.

Comment: This is the case because setTimeout is working asynchronously - it will create a new thread each time you call it, not waiting for completion. Each thread will then fire after 2 seconds. You need to use a synchronous method which waits "in place" of the loop for completion. This does not exist out of the box in JavaScript - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205283/1016343) you can find such a "busy wait" function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to make use of arrow function at this context,

```
$(".video_nav .item_container > .item").each(function(i) {
  setTimeout(() => { 
   $(this).trigger("click");
  }, i * 2000);
});
```

The problem in your code is the `this` context. Inside plain setTimeout's callBack the `this` will point to `window`. So there comes the arrow function, it will bind its nearest context's `this` value into it.

Also you have to give a delay of `(i * 2000)`, then only the delay will become 0,2000,4000 and so on. That will make you to see the callBack works with a interval of 2 secs each.

Comment: thanks got it working, why did the arrow function get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i get the question right, but you want to loop trough some elements after 2 seconds?

The solution for this problem by using Jquery:

You can use the Delay-method (https://api.jquery.com/delay/) in combination with the Queue-method (https://api.jquery.com/queue/)

```
$(".video_nav .item_container > .item").each(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    $(button).delay(2000).queue(function(){
      alert("test");
      button.trigger("click");
   });
});
```

For a working example please check this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/crix/bb4nbkts/

Hope this helps for you.